# Is this procedure recursive or iterative (long tail recursion)?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

The following code is used to implement a built-in function called *"[build-list](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=build-list#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._build-list%29%29)"*:

```
(define (my-build-list-book n f)
 (define (builder k)
   (cond [(= n k) empty]
         [else (cons (f k) (builder (add1 k)))]))
  (builder 0))

(my-build-list-book 10 add1)
>> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Is this a recursive definition of an iterative procedure or a recursive definition of a recursive procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builder` is recursive because it calls itself: `(builder (add1 k))`

It's not tail recursive because the call to itself is not done in the place where a value is returned from the original procedure. It uses the result of the recursive call as an argument to `cons` rather than as the return value.

A tail-recursive variant would end with something like:

```
[else (builder ...)]
```

Converting a function like this to tail-recursion generally requires adding an additional argument that contains the accumulated result, which is returned by the base case.

```
(define (my-build-list-book n f)
  (define (builder k result)
    (cond [(= n k) result]
          [else (builder (add1 k) (cons (f k) result))]))
  (builder 0 '()))
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "*long* tail recursion", I've never heard that phrase and I can't find it with Google.

Comment: Sorry , @Barmar . I think I messed up with the concepts. I have checked the SICP book, there is no long tail recursion... Sorry!

Comment: See also "tail-recursive modulo cons", where the compiler preallocate the cons cell and adds a `set-cdr!` operation in the generated code (or something equivalent, basically the accumulator is implicit). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons